# D3.js time scale quirk with "11 PM" values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

While using `d3.time.scale()` I am seeing some funny behaviour regarding the formatting of the tick marks.

When zooming in from months to days, sometimes I get the date format in the axis to be `%H %p` (which renders "11 PM" for example, not showing the day.) This renders like so:

> Wed 11 | Fri 13 | 11 PM | 11 PM | 11 PM ...

The dataset I am using has **day** granularity, and no time information. I would have hoped for `%a %d` (which would render Sat 15). Actually, some of the tick marks do show the correct formatting, while others do not.

Is there a way to avoid this quirk?

I was able to see this quirk in, at least, these two Mike Bostock's blocks: [Zoomable Area](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254), or [Focus+Context via Brushing](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367).

I've seen in thread "d3js: time scaling and “1901”" that a `tickFormat` property can be added to the axis, thus overriding the normal formatting. The issue here is that I want to keep the scaling formats (from years to days). I am not sure how to pass `tickFormat` a list of formats, or even only override the formatting in some situations.

Comment: Sounds like a timezone issue, see http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/9671241

Comment: @LarsKotthoff you are completely right!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because the timezone the dates are parsed with and the timezone set in the browser are different. See [this page](http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/9671241) for an explanation of the issue and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As @Lars Kotthoff pointed out, it **is** a timezone issue. The data I am using has no timezone information nor time information (e.g. "15-Aug-2000"), and the errors appear during the change date for DST periods.

To correct this issue, in my case, I changed the x-scale from:

`d3.time.scale()`, to

`d3.time.scale.utc()`.

This change (as suggested in the link [provided in Lars' comment](http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/9671241)) seems to have solved the issue.